# How to create multi criteria cost surface - Slope reclassification?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, slope, land-cover, reclassify, cost-path

I´m working on thesis aimed at investigating of possible routes and paths between Mayans cities in Guatemala. My thesis should help archaeologist to locate and reveal old paths in jungle and speed up all works in field with some scientific background.

I will use 30m DEM and anisotropic LCP approach with Tobler´s hiking equation. Problem:

I need to create multi criteria cost surface like here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000001z000000

I don´t know how to create cost raster with correct parameters. I mean I don´t know how to reclassify slope and add costs to it. I tried to use slope

1. how it was created (just derived from DEM using "Slope" function
2. reclassify slope from 1. and, of course, results are different.

I can´t find correct range for intervals and its costs. I need the same, exact range like 0-5° (cost 1), 5-8° (cost 2),... based on scientific data.

And is this correct way of solving LCP problem?

Should I create multi criteria cost surface and use it as "in_cost_raster" and Tobler equation as vertical factor in Path Distance Tool or use slope (without reclassification) as "in_cost_raster", calculate Path Distance and then add cost of Land use?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190144/toblers-hiking-function-in-pathdistance-arcgis-10-3-1/190241#190241

Comment: That's what I think too. A slope raster gives maximum slope value, which cannot be used as a cost matrix. Path distance should therefore be used, and this brings us to the Q&A mentioned by @FelixIP. Cost should be used for land cover (e.g. easier to walk on a bare soil than accross jungle).