# Combining cost analysis and voronoi-like area interpolation regarding slopes

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, voronoi-thiessen, cost-surface

I have DEM raster data of an island and I have 10 points (cities).

My task is to map the island into areas. Inside these areas everything must be nearest to the corresponding city/point, and each area must be delimited against neighboring areas where other cities are nearest. So in principle it is similar to a voronoi calculation.

The difference from a classic voronoi is that these areas must be calculated "3-dimensionally", meaning they must be defined using costs respecting how long it would take to get around the cities regarding all slopes.

Thus, e.g. a city inside mountains must result in a much smaller area than a city in flatlands (because it takes longer/has higher costs moving over the mountains than over flat land).

Of course I will need a cost analysis in GRASS in the first place. But what tools/plugins can I use to calculate the "3D-Voronoi-part" to generate my delimited areas map using this cost data?

I hope I made clear what I need to figure out how to do.

Comment: Something very similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291049/finding-least-cost-path-to-diffuse-resource-using-arcgis-pro/291608#291608 but in QGIS

Comment: I edited your question pretty heavily to improve the clarity. I hope I didn't change your meaning. If I made any mistakes you can fix them by using the [edit] link.