# Finding Least Cost Corridor in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cost-path, least-cost

Does the ArcGIS Pro feature "least cost corridor" have an equivalent module or workflow in QGIS?

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/creating-a-least-cost-corridor.htm

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about called graph simple paths problem. Basic graph below has 2^**5** = 32(!) simple paths connecting "From" and "To" nodes, because there are **5** intersections shown as a black star.

[image]

You can think of almost **any** cell in your cost surface as such intersection, so there is no way to process all possible paths and pick a set. Unless your X% is comparable with cost of a few (n) cells. If this is a case, remove n lightest cells in you cost raster and find path. These will not give you a corridor anyway.

If percent is big, try erasing entire path.

[Corridor (Spatial Analyst)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/corridor.htm) is not corridor in your understanding. It simply computes totals of 2 (Accumulated) Cost distances. Part of least cost analysis in ArcGIS is computing Cost distance (100% certain it is the case with any other GIS), after which you can compute paths.

Picture below shows such a) Cost distance b) It's sampling at Start-Finish points and 'Corridor' where for any point cost of travel to Finish is no more than 5% of 1863.

[image]

So, just use raster calculator to evaluate it from Cost Distance raster.

Comment: BTW just slope is not enough. Have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190144/toblers-hiking-function-in-pathdistance-arcgis-10-3-1#190241

Comment: Thank you. Your "corridor" example seems to be what I'm looking for. But as a cost distance calculation newbie, I still can't figure out what I have to do (which steps). Would you mind explaining this a little bit further: "So, just use raster calculator to evaluate it from Cost Distance raster." (end of your reply) That would be very helpful.

Comment: In ArcGis terms it is Con(Cdistance <= 1.03* yourNumber,1) in raster calculator window

Comment: Thank you for your highly useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we want to use QGIS to calculate a corridor around a least cost path with a total cost of 3456.78, containing all possible paths which are a maximum of 3% more expensive than the least cost path.

1. Calculate accumulated cost surface using **Accumulated cost** SAGA tool from the processing toolbox. Set route starting point as *Destinations* (as vector point and raster cell) and the raster layer that contains local cost values (e.g. slope) as *Local Cost*. For the other fields, use the default. Let's call the resulting layer *accumulated1*.
2. Repeat step 1 using route destination point as *Destinations*. Let's call the resulting layer *accumulated2*.
3. Use **Raster Calculator** tool from *Raster* menu and enter this expression:
   `(("accumulated1@1" + "accumulated2@1") < 1.03 * 3456.78) = 0`

The resulting raster layer contains 0 as value in all cells that are part of the corridor and 1 in all cells outside of it.

*(This has been tested using QGIS 3.22.)*