# Asymmetric cost distance

Tags: distance

I am interested in calculating the minimum distance of a canal necessary to irrigate any given point in a map. The problem is that the cost map would have to be asymmetric since water can flow down a slope but not up.

Is there any way of modifying the Cost Distance Tool to allow for asymmetric costs (more expensive to go from `"A"` to `"B"` than from `"B"` to `"A"`?

Comment: What software are you using Andrea? Tell a bit more about your data and what tools  and steps you have tried so far.

Comment: It's path distance tool you need, because it has vertical factor, where you can specify negative slopes only and even exclude very steep ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used path distance backlink tool plus elevation model in vertical factor. In vertical factor I used binary function to set slopes > 0 and slopes <-30 degrees as no go.

Picture below shows areas reachable from canal plus routes to 30 random points:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I thought path distance just corrected for the longer path due to elevation changes! I have about thirty other things I could apply this to!

Comment: Note that 'table' option in vertical factor is the most flexible one, e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190144/toblers-hiking-function-in-pathdistance-arcgis-10-3-1/190241#190241