# Calculating locations that could be reached by gravity aqueduct (below certain slope from sources) using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, hydrology

I am interested in finding the extent of areas that could potentially be reached by a gravity fed irrigation aqueduct from a river. I have a raster of potential sources, and a DEM. I know that for this application I must maintain a slope of at least 1:5000. I would like to calculate all cells that are within the cone of possibility from at least one of the source cells.

How could I calculate this?

E.g in cross section if 0 is the source, the lines are the limit imposed by the slope. I want to find all the locations that have an elevation lower than these bars.

I am using ArcMap.

```
      0
   /     \
 /         \
```

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck

Comment: While it might seem like asking for either of two platforms would make it more likely to get an Answer, in reality, it's more likely to get your Question closed for asking two questions. We use a Focused question/Best answer model, so you need to not only describe the data and task, but what you have attempted and the error or other problem encountered.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317843/asymmetric-cost-distance#317864

Answer (score 1):

If you have Spatial Analyst in ArcGIS, you can do this with the [Distance Accumulation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/distance-accumulation.htm) tool. Set the vertical cost parameters to make it prohibitively expensive to violate your desired slope constraint. Then you could reclassify the output raster.