# Raster Calculator Python Error 00539 for friction surface

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539, error-010240

I am trying to convert a slope raster to a friction surface with values based on Tobler's Hiking Function in ArcGIS Pro, but I get an error message I am not sure is about the formula syntax or file/path names. I first converted a DEM of part of the Florida coast with a 5-meter cell size and elevation units in centimeters to a slope raster with a Z-factor of 0.01 because I believe I had to convert centimeters (vertical units) to meters (horizontal units). When the Z-factor was 1 most of the land, including the coastline, had values greater than 45 degrees. Other than roads and reservoirs the slope raster is very flat but I would expect that for Florida.

```
Error:
 ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in rcexec_DC684390_0C54_4F14_9EBF_B34DF3F2E1B1
RuntimeError:  ERROR 010240: Could not save raster dataset to cm5_fl7_hike.tif with output format FGDBR.
 Failed to execute (RasterCalculator).
```

Parameters:

```
Map algebra expression:  (5.0 / 1000) / (6 * Exp(-3.5 * Abs(Tan(("DEMs\5M\cm5_fl7_slopem.tif" * 3.14159) / 180) + .05))) 

Output raster: d:\FLGIS\Lidar\Lidar.gdb\cm5_fl7_hike.tif
```

I am trying to replicate the following mathematical formula which was typed exactly as it was written in an article guide[image]

Comment: You can't have an extension on a file geodatabase raster. It's either TIFF in a folder with an extension or a geodatabase raster without an extension.

Comment: It's wrong to use formula like that, because slope can be both positive and negative, read on vertical factor. E.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190144/toblers-hiking-function-in-pathdistance-arcgis-10-3-1?r=SearchResults

Comment: Can I change the RC formula or should I use another tool? After trying to replicate the PDBL in your link I get nine "Error: Initialization failure in distributed distance operation." Does it have to do with using 21 points for my feature source data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating raster data in geodatabase, you do not need to add file extension such as `.tif`. This a mentioned in the help of [Create Raster Dataset](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-raster-dataset.htm):

> When storing a raster dataset in a geodatabase, do not add a file
> extension to the name of the raster dataset.