# Using Tobler's Function Equation in QGIS (Creating Friction Surface)

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, cost-surface, tobler

I'm struggling to get an equation working in QGIS that I've seen posted for ArcGIS. This [article](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1311302) has a full description. Long story short, the author modifies the original Tobler's Hiking Function for use in ArcGIS, but it won't work in QGIS Raster Calculator. I've spent a few hours working on this with no luck.

The original formula is as follows:

```
(your_res /1000)/(6 * Exp(-3.5 * Abs(Tan(("your_slope" * 3.14159)/180) + .05)))
```

"your_res" = resolution/pixel size of DEM (in this case, ASTER)
"your_slope" equals slope raster (calculated using Raster -> Analysis -> Slope).

Here's how I modified the equation for QGIS Raster Calculator:

```
(your_res / 1000) / (6 * 2.71828 ^ (-3.5 * abs ( Tan ( ( "your_slope" * 3.14159)/180) + .05)))
```

The resulting raster returns few values and basically flattens the image out. Only the most severe slope changes show any variation. I don't have ArcGIS at home to test, but that article is fairly well known to archaeologists and I suspect it works.

Comment: Tobler function has maximum at about minus 3 degrees. Your slope raster doesn't have negative values, so it's wrong path. In arcgis it's doable using vertical factor which takes direction into account.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190144/toblers-hiking-function-in-pathdistance-arcgis-10-3-1?r=SearchResults

Comment: Any ideas on creating a friction raster using this method - this equation - in QGIS?

Comment: It is not doable mate, no matter the syntax of your expression. Perhaps read my first comment again or documentation on path distance in ArcGis help

Comment: "Load  the  DEM  into  the  application  and  make  note  of  its  spatial  resolution  (cell  size)  by  right-clicking  on  it  in  the  Layers  list,  selecting Properties,  and  left-clicking  on  the  Source  tab.    If  the values   are   significantly   smaller   than   1.0   (e.g.,   .00027),   the   DEM   has   a   Geographic Latitude/Longitude  projection.    To  estimate  cell  size  in  meters  for  this  case,  a  general  rule  of thumb is to multiply the values by 100,000.  "

Comment: @nagib if it's geographic and you need metres then *project the raster*, starting off lazy is dangerous - somebody at some stage will make the mistake of believing the raster or its derived products are accurate. If your'e going to do something **do it right** or not at all.

Comment: I've tested this on several DEMs, all converted to projected CRS's. I've also resampled higher resolution DEMs to varying resolutions (10x10, 30,30). That doesn't appear to be the issue as I noted that aspect prior to attempting to create the friction surface.

Comment: @ Michael Stimson it was just a quote from a scientific paper cited by AnthroYeti ?!