# Finding distance from settlement to river in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, proximity, water

I am trying to determine how to calculate which specific settlements are within a 30-minute walk from a river polygon on ArcGIS Pro. The country I am focusing on is Nepal, thus, elevation also needs to be considered as Nepal has varying topographies. Considering that average humans can walk 1.5 to 2 miles in 30 minutes, how would I also add topographical challenges to the mix. So far I have created buffers for each settlement and that’s about it.

Comment: Navigating an elevation cost surface is a raster problem. A simple buffer isn't of much use if the path to be walked isn't direct. You need to spend some time researching the Tobler hiking function.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190144/toblers-hiking-function-in-pathdistance-arcgis-10-3-1#190241